# Belgrade SqlClient -> Response won't finish

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, webapi

What I want to do is just send a (large) json output (for json path) from the Stored Procedure (MS SQL) to the Web API caller. 
I use http://jocapc.github.io/Belgrade-SqlClient/aspnet.html for requesting SQL Server. This is because I read this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1106622/Building-REST-services-with-ASP-NET-Core-Web-API-a
Firefox recieve results (text only, no formatted json), but the request never ends. PostMan shows no results.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int rows)
    {

        ICommand cmd = new Command(connStr);

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse();
        response.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, content, context) => 
        {
            await cmd
            .Proc("cuh.GetADDRESSES")
            .Param("@rows", rows)
            .Stream(stream, "[]");
        }, "application/json");

        //response.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true;

        return response;

    }
```

I read this can happen when the stream is not closed in the end of the request. But I don't know how to do this in this case.
Any other working approach for working with json output from stored proc would be appreciated. Same for the other direction: Write JSON directly into the database with a stored proc through a nvarchar(max) parameter (stored proc code is not my problem).

Comment: Is the command ever started?

Comment: Yes, Firefox is recieving the text output. I try with one row transformed to json and a lot of rows. It works, but it seems that firefox is endless waiting for more...

Comment: Could it be the output is just massive? Have you tried writing it to file to see if that ever ends?

Answer (score 0):

Much easier than expected:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int rows)
    {

        ICommand cmd = new Command(connStr);

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse();
        response.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, content, context) => 
        {

            await cmd
            .Proc("cuh.GetADDRESSES")
            .Param("@rows", rows)
            .Stream(stream, "[]");

            stream.Dispose();//This is the missing part to get it work

        }, "application/json");

        return response;

    }
```